# Ruby - checking ping status featback with ssh, backtick via ssh?

Tags: ruby, ssh, backticks

In my project I want to write a script to check if every device in my network is online/reachable. I have a method called pingtest and it works for now..

```
def pingtest(destination)
    system("ping -n 2 #{destination}")
    if $? == 0                                #checking status of the backtick
        puts "\n Ping was successful!"
    else
        close("Device is unreachable. Check the config.txt for the correct IPs.")
        #close() is just print & exit..
    end
end
```

Now I wanted to ping via a ssh session with an other device in my network:

```
#--------------------------------
require 'net/ssh' 
Net::SSH.start(@ip, @user, :password => @password)
#--------------------------------

@ssh = Ssh.new(@config)
@ssh.cmd("ping -c 3 #{@IP}")
```

The ping works fine but how can I use my backtrack idea now to determine if it was succesful or not?
 
I thought about using a sftp connection..

> "ping -c 3 #{@IP} => tmpfile.txt" => download => check/compare => delete

(or something like that) to check if it was correct, but im not statusfied with that. Is there a possibility to check the success status like I did before? 
I also tried something like this..

```
result = @ssh.cmd("ping -c 3 #{@IP}")
if result.success? == 0 # and so on..
```

I startet learning ruby some days ago, so im a newbie looking forward for your ideas to help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Net::SSH to run the command remotely, similarly to what you've already got there.

The `result` returned from running the command will be whatever is written to both `stdout` and `stderr`.

You can use the contents of that returned value to check if it was successful or not.

```
Net::SSH.start(@ip, @user. password: @password) do |ssh|
  response = ssh.exec! "ping -c 3 #{@other_ip}"
  if response.include? 'Destination Host Unreachable'
    close("Host unreachable. Result was: #{result}")
  else
    puts "\n Ping was successful"
  end
end
```

Comment: `'block in (mymethod)': undefined local variable or method 'response' for #<Ssh...> <NameError>`
Seems like there is something missing. I tried several things but now I think that I just dont have the reponse method.. Do I need to implement something else?

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, renamed some variables and forgot one. I've fixed it up.